# .NET Core Class Library project: missing ADO.net Entity Data Model template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a .NET Core 3.0 class library project, and would like to use Entity Framework in it.

I have installed Entity Framework Core using Nuget, and also have .NET Core 3.0 SDK installed on my computer, but I still don't see the ADO.net Entity Data Model template when I try to add a new item to the project.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Comment: I guess you have to use some other [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) like the EF Core Power Tools...

Comment: if you are creating DB context from the existing database you need to use scaffolding to do that. refer https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx for more info

Comment: Deleting questions while people are trying to answer is annoying. Check the [Microsoft API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) libraries, they may *already* do what you want.

Comment: The [API Documentation Wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation) in that repo explains how to use the packages, how to handle versioning in general and how to [configure](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Versioning-Options) the library to use specific versions, including [how to set the default API version](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Versioning-Options#default-api-version)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to scaffold my entities by running `dotnet-ef` command line.
Install the following package first :

```
> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

And the `dotnet-ef` tool :

```
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Then issue the below command :

```
> dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=your_server_instance;Database=your_db;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model
```

Please have a look at this :
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

Answer (score -1):

When creating a new project, there is

1. Class Library (.Net Standard), at the top of the list, and
2. Class Library (.Net Framework), somewhere lower in the list

Use the second one.